# ZF1 resultando do controller na view

Tags: php, zend

Não estou entendo como neste caso jogar os valores na view do projeto, segue o código:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $actor = new Application_Model_Actor();
    $resultadoActores = $actor->listarAtor();

    foreach($resultadoActores as $ator)
    {

        $idActor = $ator->actor_id;

        $film_actor = new Application_Model_FilmActor();
        $resultadoFilmeAtores = $film_actor->listarFilmeActorId($idActor);

        foreach ($resultadoFilmeAtores as $filmeAtor)
        {

            $idFilm = $filmeAtor->film_id;

            $film = new Application_Model_Film();
            $resultadoFilmes = $film->listarFilmeId($idFilm);

            foreach ($resultadoFilmes as $filme)
            {
                echo $ator->first_name . " " . $filme->title . "<br/>"; // <-- Esse resultado na view?
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Tentei fazer algo do tipo: $this->view->filmes = $resultadoFilmes; e lá dentro da view do controller criar o foreach e atribuir os valores, mas sem sucesso também.

Answer (score 2):

Eu acredito que o problema seja mais de lógica do que com o Zend Framework 1.

Se você fizer o código que disse

```
$this->view->filmes = $resultadoFilmes;
```

Você só vai pegar os filmes do último  ator, que  pode  ser  nenhum filme.

Reescrevendo o código da sua controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $actor = new Application_Model_Actor();
    $resultadoActores = $actor->listarAtor();

    //variável para guardar filmes
    $filmes = array();

    foreach($resultadoActores as $ator)
    {

        $idActor = $ator->actor_id;


        $film_actor = new Application_Model_FilmActor();
        $resultadoFilmeAtores = $film_actor->listarFilmeActorId($idActor);



        foreach ($resultadoFilmeAtores as $filmeAtor)
        {

            $idFilm = $filmeAtor->film_id;

            $film = new Application_Model_Film();
            $resultadoFilmes = $film->listarFilmeId($idFilm);

            foreach($resultadoFilmes as $resultadoFilme){
                $filmes[] = array(
                    'ator' => $ator->first_name, 
                    'filme' => $resultadoFilme->title
                );
            }
        }
    }

    $this->view->filmes = $filmes;
}
```

Na view, simplesmente:

```
<?php foreach($this->filmes as $filme): ?>
<?php echo $filme['ator'] ?> <?php echo $filme['filme'] ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Fontes:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.view.controllers.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.view.scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

Como estás a fazer na view para consumir os dados?
deveria ser do género:

```
<?php foreach($resultadoFilmes as $filme): ?>
<?php echo $filme->title; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Ajudou?